# c# datatable to webpage through AJAX call Error

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax

I am trying to do this for the first time based on modifying a code snippet I found online.  I am building an html data table in my code behind embedding sql data from a c# datatable.  I am then trying to pass it to an .aspx page using an AJAX call and passing the html table string to a  tag.  The problem I am having is that when I breakpoint on the htmlTable string it looks good but the page is coming up with a javascript alert box saying 'error', not sure how to troubleshoot from this point or what is wrong with the code, I have pasted below, any assistance is appreciated!!!
Code Behind:

```
 namespace WebApplication3
{
    public partial class Page_MF : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private static string connTotalOrdersCalls = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connTotalOrdersCalls"].ConnectionString;

        public static DataTable reportDT()
        {
            try
            {            
            String sp_Name = "USP_TOTAL_ORDERCALLS";
            using (DataTable OrdersCalls = new DataTable())
            {
                OrdersCalls.Columns.Add("Week_Ending");
                OrdersCalls.Columns.Add("Mth");
                OrdersCalls.Columns.Add("Product_Suite");
                OrdersCalls.Columns.Add("Site");
                OrdersCalls.Columns.Add("SalesAction");
                OrdersCalls.Columns.Add("Orders");
                OrdersCalls.Columns.Add("TotalCalls");
                using (SqlConnection SQLConn = new SqlConnection(connTotalOrdersCalls))
                {
                    using(SqlCommand SQLComm = new SqlCommand(sp_Name, SQLConn))
                    {
                        SQLComm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        //SQLComm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Site", null);
                        SQLConn.Open();

                        SqlDataReader sql_Reader = SQLComm.ExecuteReader();
                        while (sql_Reader.Read())
                        {
                            Object[] row = {
                                               sql_Reader["Week_Ending"].ToString(),
                                               sql_Reader["MTH"].ToString(),
                                               sql_Reader["PRODUCT_SUITE"].ToString(),
                                               sql_Reader["SITE"].ToString(),
                                               sql_Reader["Orders"].ToString(),
                                           };
                            OrdersCalls.Rows.Add(row);
                        }
                    }

                return OrdersCalls;
            }
        }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        [WebMethod]
        public static String SendToDiv()
        {
            String htmlTable = "<table>";
            DataTable newTable = reportDT();

            for (int i = 0; i < newTable.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                htmlTable += "<tr>";
                for (int x = 0; x < newTable.Columns.Count; x++)
                {
                    htmlTable += "<td>" + newTable.Rows[i][x] + "</td>";
                }
                htmlTable += "</tr>";
            }
            return htmlTable;
        }
    }
}
```

.ASPX Page:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 

    <script type="text/javascript">
    //on document ready event (when the dom is ready)
    $(document).ready(function () {
        appendToDiv();
    });

    function appendToDiv() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            async: false,  
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "Page_MF.aspx/SendToDiv",
            data: JSON.stringify({}), 
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {

                $('#div-for-upload').append(data.d)
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="div-for-upload">
   </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: launch developer console in your browser (F12) and put a breakpoint at the line with alert(). check what the "result" variable contains and update your question. you can also launch debugger in visual studio and check whether your method is called and whether it outputs correct data.

Comment: Hi what actually resolved this for me was adding the following to my web.config, I think the amount of test data I was using was too large.  

  <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="50000000">
        </jsonSerialization>
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>

Answer (score 0):

according to the description you provided, below are possibilities. 
 1) Copy the value from htmlTable string variable. Create a HTML page and paste these content in the body section. If page displays the info, be sure, nothing wrong with the table creation. 
**In the provided solution, you must close the table node.**

2) Check the response from developer tool like Firebug, Chrome developer tool by pressing F12 function key. It should show you the contents are being passed from server to client.

[image: e.g. of Firefox firebug response]

If you can see the response, your data is on the client side.

3) This condition limits us to the final option i.e you're accessing / trying to access wrong field for the data from the response.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi what actually resolved this for me was adding the following to my web.config, I think the amount of test data I was using was too large. <system.web.extensions> <scripting> <webServices> <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="50000000"> </jsonSerialization> </webServices> </scripting> </system.web.extensions> –

Comment: Glad to know, you've found the answer. Thanks